# c# .net Core add grpc server on an existing solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, grpc

i would to know if it was possible to add a gRPC server to an existing solution, a service that works on windows, it's for manage configuration and receive some informations. (Visual Studio)

The only way i found for the while is to make it from a virgin project and transform it in library, but i can't add it directly in my solution like with a wcf server.

I have a problem on the proto part, i can't add one by using the menu "add an element" this type of file is not present even with gRPC core nugget installed, and if i change compilation and compile it as proto file it don't work because that don't generate the partial class.

edit: 
I found to generate the partial class, i must add a service reference to the proto file then click on it in the gRPC list.
Always impossible to add easily a proto file when adding a new element, i must add a txt file, complete it then edit to add proto informations.

Edit 2:
To have the possibility to add proto files you must change the project balise to Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web" (obtain all function available for a new grpc Project)

There is an additionnal point, i followed the Microsoft's tutorial and there is a bad way about proto files, they said to copy the proto file when you make a client. Instead of doing like that, add a service reference, point on the proto file of the server ! Now all is synchronized when you edit the proto's server file.

Comment: You can add a .proto file into the project. If your dependencies are correct (Grpc.AspNetCore) building should be enough to generate the corresponding c# assembly.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer i looked about this, it's ok for package but i have difference between my project and a gRPC service on FrameWork and Analyzers parts.